# VS Code Studio - Python - Saving Data permanently?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code Studio with Python and would like to save the data I create so it can be reused in future sessions. At the moment I'm having to run all my code every time which is annoying! Is there a way to set up a library or workspace which I code save and reload data from easily?

Thanks

Comment: use the `pickle` module to save/load python data

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on what type of data you're trying to save, what your requirements are for saving/retrieving it, etc. Unfortunately, without more requisite details, this question is simply not answerable as it currently stands. [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by 2 ways:

1. You can save everything in a .py file, and add a function to run it as soon as you start the program by this:

   import os
   os.startfile('path of file mentioned above')
2. If it is some sort of data you can save it and run it using os module which you don't need to install it already comes with python.

Tip: You may use pickle too to save or load the data.

Comment: I would emphasize that, although pickle does take more overhead on the learning curve, it is a great solution for several cases like this one in the long term. It is definitely worth giving a look at it even if it takes more time to set up.

Comment: yes you're correct